# Cron doesn't work after moving CiviCRM to sudomain

Tags: joomla, cron, migration

For PHP version reason, I move Joomla! & CiviCRM from example.org/civicrm to civicrm.example.org.
I changed all civicrm.settings.php in admin and frontend folders and I emptied the cache, template_c and log folder and CIVICRM_SITE_KEY is always the same.
Everything works fine and cron URL could be fetch (blank screen on the web but Status: 200 after crontab run)
So, no mailing is sent automatically. But I can send it when I run the task manually ?!

On CiviCRM status, I can read that no cron is running. But at tihs time, I really don't know where to find to resolve this issue.

I tried both https://example.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=&pass=&key= and the command wget -O - -q -t 1 'https://example.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=&pass=&key=', results are OK but CiviCRM doesn't recognize those execution.

I also tried to change PHP version (7.4, 8.0 and 8.1), without any change. I only have a warning about session when I display PHP errors.

On this thread [For some reason, cron doesn't work. On CMS joomla](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27661/for-some-reason-cron-doesnt-work-on-cms-joomla), I note that the cron user must be a super-admin, but I tested and it only work once : now, there is an error status with cron in CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [`cv` method](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cv)? That works well.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't find it on Joomla! and I don't find how to write the cron task. And now with J!4, the usual cron task doesn't work anymore.